# bit selection in C not working when MSB and LSB are the same

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

i'm trying to write a bit select function that returns the bits between the starting bit and ending bit of the given number (inclusive), but my program doesn't work when the starting and ending bit is the same value. what am i doing wrong?

```
int bit_select(int num, int start, int end) {
        int s = 8*sizeof(int)-1;
        if (start != s) {
                start++;
        }
        unsigned int shifted = num << ((s+1) - start);
        
        return shifted;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `num` be an unsigned int?

Comment: You should provide us with sample input and output along with the expected results.

Comment: `8*sizeof(int)-1` seems like the wrong calculation.

Comment: @tadman why is that?

Comment: @shrewmouse i don't think so, i think its just the shift? my header file says it should be just int.

Comment: Is this assuming that the `int` is signed, so you're skipping the sign bit?

Comment: Maybe add a couple of examples of inputs and expected output.

Comment: I added an example input and expected output.

Comment: Your sample input/output implies that you want the bit(s) right shifted. That is, if start is equal to end, the result can only be 0 or 1?

Comment: Need more examples. `0xe7e7` is binary `1110 0111 1110 0111` so bit 3 _is_ zero and _not_ one

Comment: To further clarify on the shifting, from `bit_select(0xe7e7,7,4)` do you want: `0x00e0` or `0x000e`?

Comment: for `bit_select(0xE7E7, 7, 4)`, The outcome should be just `0xe`.

Comment: I added another example

Comment: Function return type is `int` and you return `unsigned`.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to the examples that shows how you decided what the output should be. It's not at all obvious to me how you come to the conclusion that `bit_select(0xe7e7, 3, 3)` should be 1 (I would have guessed 0), or `bit_select(0xFFFFFFFF, 31, 31)` should be 8 (I would have guessed 1).

Comment: What are you thinking? `bit_select(0xFFFFFFFF, 31, 31)` should return 0x1 and _not_ 0x8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that I created from scratch, based on the top comments [yours and mine] with a simple diagnostic suite:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int num_t;

#define DOTEST(_fnc) \
    do { \
        res = _fnc(val,beg,end); \
        printf(" %s=%8.8X",#_fnc,res); \
    } while (0)

num_t
craig(num_t val,int beg,int end)
{
    num_t msk = 1;
    num_t res;

    res = val;

    msk <<= (beg + 1);
    msk -= 1;
    if (msk != 0)
        res &= msk;

    res >>= end;

#if 0
    printf("craig: val=%8.8X msk=%8.8X res=%8.8X beg=%d end=%d\n",
        val,msk,res,beg,end);
#endif

    return res;
}

int
molly(int num, int start, int end)
{
    int s = 8 * sizeof(int) - 1;

    if (start != s) {
        start++;
    }
    unsigned int shifted = num << ((s + 1) - start);

    shifted = shifted >> ((s + 1) - start + end);

    return shifted;
}

int
molly2(unsigned int num, int start, int end)
{
    int s = 8 * sizeof(int) - 1;

    if (start != s) {
        start++;
    }
    unsigned int shifted = num << ((s + 1) - start);

    shifted = shifted >> ((s + 1) - start + end);

    return shifted;
}

void
dotest(num_t val,int beg,int end)
{
    num_t res;

    printf("dotest: %8.8X",val);
    DOTEST(craig);
    DOTEST(molly);
    DOTEST(molly2);
    printf(" %d/%d\n",beg,end);
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(0xe7e7,3,3);
    dotest(0xe7e7,7,4);
    dotest(0xe7e7,7,5);
    dotest(0xFFFFFFFF,31,31);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
dotest: 0000E7E7 craig=00000000 molly=00000000 molly2=00000000 3/3
dotest: 0000E7E7 craig=0000000E molly=0000000E molly2=0000000E 7/4
dotest: 0000E7E7 craig=00000007 molly=00000007 molly2=00000007 7/5
dotest: FFFFFFFF craig=00000001 molly=FFFFFFFE molly2=FFFFFFFE 31/31
```